# Google Colaboratory gives me an error when I want to install OpenSlide

Tags: google-colaboratory

When I ran the following commands in the Jupiter notebook, it gives me an error.

```
!apt-get install openslide-tools
!pip install openslide-python
```

*ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.*

It was working before but right now it gives me an error when I try to run it.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have to install the python libraries for openslide through [apt-get](https://openslide.org/download/#windows-binaries). Try this

`!apt-get install openslide-tools 
!apt-get install python3-openslide`

Comment: I keep getting the daunting error message: TileSourceException: No available tilesource for exapmle_image.ndpi although I know that this file is there and I could open it in other saturn (not google collaboration) instances. Anybody has an idea why?